# How to append text to file

Tags: c#

I created an "e-mail account database". You can create an account by entering your e-mail and password in a textbox. Finally, the e-mail and password are saved in a text file.

The code can be found here:
http://prntscr.com/9fzt6u

An output example can be found here:
http://prntscr.com/9fztbe

The problem is that everytime I add a new account, the existing one is overwritten. I would like to know how to append a new account to my text file.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use other override

```
using(StreamWriter str = new StreamWriter("c:\\file.txt", true))
{
//todo
}
```

**true** check if file exists to append new line else create new file

Comment: Thanks alot guys for you replys :) I did it ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to append the text instead of override. [Look at this constructor for StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Set `append` to true and it will work fine.